# 401 redirect_uri_mismatch with .net core web application?

Tags: asp.net-core, google-drive-api, google-oauth

Authorization Error
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy.

If you're the app developer, register the redirect URI in the Google Cloud Console.

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]

Answer (score 0):

The redirect uri sit he URI where you are telling the authorization server to return authorization to.   This uri must be registered in Google developer console for your project.

So redirect uri miss match means that your application is telling the authorization server to return the authorization code to a uri that you have not configured in Google developer console.  The easiest solution is to take the uri its telling you is missing and simply add it.

This video will show you how to add it. [Google OAuth2: How the fix redirect_uri_mismatch error.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHz1Rs6lZHQ)